# No Line-out audio - P8Z68-V Pro, ALC892

Tags: audio-jack

Trying to get my rear panel Audio Out (Line Out) port/s to work.  Have spent much of the last four days wandering the Web looking for a solution but so far no luck so requesting personalized assistance.

Motherboard:    ASUS  P8Z68-V Pro
BIOS:       American Megatrends version 3603    11/09/2012  (most-current version)
CPU:        Intel i5-2500K  3.30 GHz    Quad-core
Communication:  Intel   6 Series/C200 Series Chipset
Multimedia – Audio Device:  Intel   6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
    Configuration: driver = snd_hda_intel
Codec   Realtek ALC892
Ubuntu 18.04.3 (64-bit) with LivePatch activated

Think that’s the basic get-started info needed – anything else ask!  ...Uploaded my Alsa-Info.sh results to http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=4a04377cd3f1ee277521f7b646f100854d74583b

Using an amplified speaker set to test.  Not a peep except for a ‘blerp’ when powering up.  Plug into a DAC and hear “Front Left, Front Right”.   Plugged a set of earphones into the built-in jacks but didn’t hear anything.

Currently BIOS settings are:
BIOS  settings: (Advanced > Onboard Devices > HD Audio Controller)
    HD Audio Controller = Enabled
    Front Panel Type    = HD
    SPDIF Out Type  = SPDIF
Played with various combinations and just managed get Dummy Speaker (something like that) if shut off the controller and a change to the options in Settings > Sound.

alsamixer – appears things are configured correctly: cranked up the controls and nobody muted that shouldn’t be.

pavucontrol – can see the meter pulse – assume with the voice.

Had tried the uninstall and re-install instructions,  various “options snd-hda-intel model=” in /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf,

Have noticed several times it appears if pavucontrol and/or Settings > Sounds > Speaker-Testing is up for a long time and nothing being done the computer locks up.   “Ignore” for ten minutes or so – locked up while I was typing these notes.  CTRL_ALT_F2 didn’t work but REISUB did work.  (No idea if that detail is significant.)  At the lockup the mouse did not move, no seconds update (on the clock).

If I have speaker-test -c2 -twav -Dplughw:0,1 with pavucontrol running in another Terminal will bet a “Playback open error: -16,Device or resource busy”.  Using 0,1 the ‘response text’ of speaker-test displays at a normal scroll rate but no VU indication noted in pavucontrol.  Stop (^C) speaker-test, leaving pavucontrol running (not touch that Terminal window), run speaker testing at Settings > Sound and I do get a VU display.  No sound still (powered speakers plugged in to Line Out.)

OK, something’s not connecting and hopefully someone out there can help me find what it is.

TIA!

Barry

-=-  -=-  -=-

Added Oct 4 -- too long for comment which would be in-line:

Hi!  Appreciate the assistance but admit to snooping around to try to find clues or even a solution.  At this site http://www.volkerschatz.com/noise/alsa.html he has a utility called ‘alsacap’.  Normally I don’t install random stuff but since it’s broken now can’t make it much worse.   Did get a fatal error which may indicate a problem.  From my notes:

BJM: Trying to create this utility to help test for the problem.  ==>
    make -f Makefile   ==>   fatal error: alsa/asoundlib.h  no such file or directory

```
So where is this supposed to be??
    find  / -type d  -iname alsa   2>/dev/null     gives numerous possibilities:
            /run/alsa
            /var/lib/alsa
            /usr/share/sounds/alsa
            /usr/share/alsa
        (Others but in snap, timeshift, etc.)

    find  / -type f  -iname asound*   2>/dev/null     (extract logical possibilities):
            /run/lock/asound.state.lock
            /var/lib/alsa/asound.state
            /usr/include/sound/asound_fm.h
            /usr/include/sound/asound.h

    find  / -type f  -iname asoundl*   2>/dev/null    ==> nothing
```

The file    /run/lock/asound.state.lock   seems suspicious to me; looks like just has “ 824   (bunch of spaces).”   Only thing visible is the 824; just trying to be complete.

Comment: This comment thread has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99582/discussion-on-question-by-bjm-no-line-out-audio-p8z68-v-pro-alc892). Everyone involved should be able to chat in that room, but please let me know if you have trouble doing so.

Comment: First question is usually does it work in Windows? Otherwise it might be a hardware problem. Your motherboard claims 8 channel audio out. Is this correct?: https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P8Z68V/

Comment: To keep us Google-for-the-answer folks up to date, Paul and I were requested to move this to a private chat area.  Paul has been very helpful but unfortunately we have not been able to resolve.  Appears the motherboard has some quirks.  I am currently trying a SoundBlaster SB1570 card as a work-around and that card isn’t being detected at all (!).  Stay tuned!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was a hardware compatibility problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much as I don't like to give up I have decided to go with a 5.1 DAC and get on with things.  As of this writing is on order; tested with a 2.0/2.1 unit and works.